# Maven: utility to generate unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, maven-2, code-generation

I need to write unit tests for an existing Java REST server.

The GET methods are very similar and I am thinking that I can write a small unit test generator that will use reflection to introspect the GET methods and the POJOs they consume to generate (boilerplate) unit tests.

Each test will be generated with a small syntax error so that they cannot be run as is, but must be examined by a developer and the syntax error corrected. I am hoping that this will as least assure that the tests are sane and look reasonable.

The generator will be run from the command line, passing in the class-under-test, the output directory for the unit tests, etc.

I don't want the class files for the generator to be added to the WAR file, but the generator needs to have access to the class files for the REST server.

My project directory is a "standard" Maven hierarchy: project/src/main/java, project/target, etc.

Where is the best place to put the generator source code? Under project/src/main/java? Under  project/src/generator/java? Somewhere else?

I know how to exclude the generated class files from the WAR file if they all are included under a specific package (e.g. com.example.unit_test_generator).

Answer (score 1):

This scenario sound like a maven-plugin to me. Furthermore the usual place for generated code is under target/generated... which means target folder ...take a look at maven-antlr3-plugin or maven-jaxb-plugin to see where they usually put generated code into. Never put generated code into src/ structure...But may be you have to change the location and to put into project/src/main/ ...But if these classes are some kind of tests the have to be located under project/src/test instead.

Comment: "Never put generated code into src/ structure" - this is really pseudo-generated source code. It is not meant to be regenerated with each build, but only once when a new GET resource is created. That is why I am using the command-line to run the generator.

Comment: Ah Ok...different story. Thanks for the explanation.